# Inserting a UIView header in a UIWebView's ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, embed

Is it possible to have a custom `UIView` header that is part of the same scroll view as a `UIWebView`? if so, how could this be implemented?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656328/uiwebview-with-header-and-footer/38118077#38118077

Comment: make uiview scroll with webview. http://stackoverflow.com/q/43533068/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIScrollView` with the content size of your header + `UIWebView`.

When doing so, in the delegate of your `UIWebView`, catch when the web has finished loading and resize the `UIWebView` according to its content, and make its `UIScrollView` non-scrollable.

Answer (score 3):

If you would need the headerView to move up and down with the webView (like in the mail app on iOS) but, of course, not change it's position when you zoom, it is a bit more complicated than that.

I ran into the same situation and so I put my solution on gitHub, in case someone else needs it :) Here's the [project](https://github.com/catalinaturlea/HeaderWebView)

Comment: You're welcome, really hope it helps! If you find any bugs or problems with it just let me know :)